# Why doesn't preempt_disable increase the value returned by preempt_count?

Tags: linux-kernel

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int init_module(void)
{
  printk("preempt_count: %d\n", preempt_count());
  preempt_disable();
  printk("preempt_count: %d\n", preempt_count());
  preempt_enable();

  return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
  printk("cleanup_module\n");
}
```

The above code prints the following messages to /var/log/syslog:

```
Sep 13 16:31:29 userver kernel: [  600.835013] preempt_count: 0
Sep 13 16:31:29 userver kernel: [  600.835017] preempt_count: 0
```

Why does the preempt_count after the preempt_disable still return 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the kernel is not compiled with `CONFIG_PREEMPT`, there is no preemption counter.